# Aws iOS sdk Pre-singed url giving "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Have problem accessing file using presigned url generated by aws sdk, given all necessary permission for the bucket.

I have downloaded the sample code from there github and changed the below
**Awscredential provider** as per my requirement.

**The changes are below**

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider =[[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:S3AccessKey secretKey:S3secretKey];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Even though i upload the file sucessfully to aws I am not able to access them using the presigned url which i get from the aws sdk while uploading.

Can anyone point out the things i am missing in order to access the files using presigned url.

when url is loaded in browser SignatureDoesNotMatch error is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with presigned url encoding. In **iOS** and **android** sdks (not in windows) you need to **encode the query string** in the Presigned url again.

NEWURL=baseurl +(encoded query String);

**NEWURL is the correct url you can access.**

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The most possible reason for "SignatureDoesNotMatch" is the contents in header-field are different from the one provided while generating the presigned url.

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate how to generate and download a file by using presigned url:

```
AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = @"bucketname";
    getPreSignedURLRequest.key = @"keyname";
    getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodGET;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

    AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder *preSignedURLBuilder = [AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder];

    [[[preSignedURLBuilder getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        if (task.error) {
            XCTAssertNil(task.error);
            return nil;
        }

        NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
        //NSLog(@"(GET)presigned URL is: %@",presignedURL.absoluteString);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

        NSError *returnError = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *returnResponse = nil;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnResponse error:&returnError];

        return nil;
    }] waitUntilFinished];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, you need to register PreSignedURL builder.

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider =[[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:S3AccessKey secretKey:S3secretKey];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

// Register S3 PreSignedURL Builder
[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder registerS3PreSignedURLBuilderWithConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"configuration_name"];


AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder * urlBuilder  = [AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder S3PreSignedURLBuilderForKey:@"configuration_name"];
```